# length property not being captured

Tags: javascript

I know I have to be doing something dumb here. Just need a second set of eyes.

Validating if my radio box has been checked:

```
<input type="radio" name="cont_amt" id="cont_amt" value="1000">

  //alert(theForm.cont_amt.value);
  var con_optLength = theForm.cont_amt.length;
  var chkd="";

  for(var i = 0; i < con_optLength; i++) {
        if(theForm.cont_amt[i].checked) {
            chkd=theForm.cont_amt[i].value;
        }
  }


if ( chkd == "" ) {
      reason += "\t" + "Must select a contribution option" + "\n";
  }
```

I'm always hitting my alert because my `length` is always undefined.

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/vpGHd/ Assuming you have more radios with the same name.

Comment: I was using some old code that where I had many more radio buttons. For this page, I only have one with the same name.

Comment: @emt124: In that case, there's no need to loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with [`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName).

```
  var con = document.getElementsByName('cont_amt');
  var chkd = null;

  for(var i = 0; i < con.length; i++) {
        if(con[i].checked) {
            chkd = con[i].value;
        }
  }
```

And here is a [nice jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y8SJy/) to see that I'm not lying.

**Note:** I suspect you do this because you have several radio buttons like this. If this is the case, you should remove the ID attribute because it must be unique in the document.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have only one radiobutton by the name "cont_amt". Add at least one more for the property "length" to become available.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `theForm.cont_amt` is an Object not an Array.

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YavfP/).